# Add/remove rules based on select value, jQuery Validate

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-validate

I have the following code:

```
$( "#select" ).change(function() {
  var requiredvalue = $("#select").val();
  console.log(requiredvalue);
  $('#fieldtoberequired').rules("add", {
    required: requiredvalue
  });
});
```

The select can have the values true or false. When it's true I need the #fieldtoberequired to be required, and when it's false I need it to not be required.

When reading required value in the console, it switches between true and false like expected. But the field remains non-required.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following instead:

```
$('#fieldtoberequired').prop('required', requiredvalue);
```

Comment: Turns out the value was `"true"` and not `true`. My bad. Thanks for the help, though, the above should work as well.

Comment: @pshoeg, please don't forget to write the solution as an answer and "accept" it.  Otherwise, simply accept the best answer.